# How to get the last value of an ArrayList in kotlin?

Tags: arraylist, kotlin

How to get the last item of an ArrayList in kotlin?

I  have a list like

```
val myList = listOf("item1", "item2", "item3")
```

I want to get the last item of myList

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There's [`last()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/last.html) method, created exactly for this purpose.

```
myList.last()
```

Comment: It might cause NoSuchElementException if list is empty. Use with caution.

Comment: there is [lastOrNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/last-or-null.html) for that, so you dont get an exception

Answer (score 1):

As @DownloadPizza said in the comments of the accepted answer, to avoid an exception you should use `.lastOrNull()`:

```
val lastItemInList = list.lastOrNull()

if (lastItemInList != null) {

    println(lastItemInList)
}
```